# Capture image and display in same activity in android - Image Preview is blurred

Tags: android

I'm developing a code to capture an image and then display the same in preview mode. Capturing of the image works fine. But while displaying it in the activity, I get the image as a blurred one. Can please someone throw some light on the possible solution? (Refer my code below)

**PreviewImageActivity.java**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.image_capture);

        cam_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

public void captureclick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // user is returning from capturing an image using the camera

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                Bitmap captured = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Image Details");
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Height: " + thePic.getHeight() + "Width: " + thePic.getWidth()).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);
            full_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image);
                full_img.setImageBitmap(captured);
```

}

**image_capture.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="captureclick"
    android:src="@drawable/camera_icon"
    android:text="@string/Click" />
```

**activity_full_screen.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/full_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/full_image_desc" />
```

Comment: set android:adjustViewBounds="true" for imageview

Comment: @BirajZalavadia: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried using that attribute, still the image is blurred while previewing it. No luck. Could you please help me analyze further? More information if needed, would be provided. Thanks in advance.